# Android-programmable particle effects

Tags: java, android, particle-system

Can any android (or java) experts point me to graphics libraries, code samples and or examples that make use of particle effects?

I am trying to create dynamic particle effects similar to what can be achieved via plugins in After Effects, but using code

http://cache.redgiantsoftware.com/_assets/uploads/file/products-examples/Form%20Up%20to%20H%20Web-h264_mq.mov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) has a very easy to use particle effect system and editor and it runs on desktop and Android

You can find an official tutorial [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2d-particle-effects)

I'm not sure if it will do exactly what you need but there are a lot of options to customize the system in the editor and in code.

Some sample code from my own project:

```
private ParticleEffect effect;

//constructor
effect = new ParticleEffect();
effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("data/explosion.p"), Gdx.files.internal("data"));

//render
effect.start();
effect.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
effect.draw(batch, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```